# undefined method `explain' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, but I have followed some tutorials and know my way around a little bit. I have generated some scaffolding and inserted data into a MySql database.

When navigating to index.html.erb I receive the error in the title

The controller is executing index

```
  def index
    @beers = Beer.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @beers }
    end
  end
```

And has this as a structure

```
Beer: id, brewer_id, name, price, score, color, brew_type, create_at, updated_at
```

RoR is working for other scaffolding I have created, and listing data. I updated the structure in mysql for the entity Beer, and it probably hasn't reflected changes in rails (dunno).

Do I need a different gem for connecting rails to a mysql db? Any advice on what to check for would be appreciated (:

Comment: "I updated the structure in mysql..." What changes did you make?

Comment: I added an index on brewer_id so that I could use a foreign key and link it back to id of the brewer entity. Changed created_at and updated_at to both be a timestamp (changed from datetime). First had "brew_type" labeled as "type," but realized that "type" was a reserved heading (I reflected this "type" change in my index.html.erb)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using Rails 3.2 and that your `Beer.all` call is taking too long. From the [3.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#automatic-query-explains):

> Queries that take more than half a second to run are **automatically** explained in the development mode. This threshold, of course, can be changed.

And if we look at the [MySQL adapter for Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html), there is no `explain` method. However, the [MySQL2 adapter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Mysql2Adapter.html#method-i-explain) does understand `explain`.

First of all, you probably need less beer or some pagination. Then, you should try switching to the MySQL2 adapter; just install the new adapter by editing your `Gemfile` to use `mysql2`, run `bundle` to get the new stuff set up, and then change your `database.yml` to look more like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
```

Comment: ooo! Ill try the new adapter, about 6000 in my list right now

Comment: YES, this fixed it. Using mysql2 now. And you are right about having it take more than 1/2 a sec. I am just in development phase right now, and will have some pagination. Thanks!

Comment: I've another gem (twitter) that needs the older version of mysql. How do I fix that?

Comment: @singhspk: Patch the gem to use mysql2 or disable auto-explain by setting `config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = nil` in your `config/environments/development.rb`. Fixing the gem to require mysql or mysql2 would make the most sense.

Comment: @muistooshort: I'm new to rails. How do you do this:  Fixing the gem to require mysql or mysql2?

Comment: @singhspk: That might be a bit much if you're new to Rails. Which twitter gem requires MySQL? That seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: You almost didn't get my +1 because of the sentence "First of all, you probably need less beer...". What sort of solution is THAT?? ;-)