# auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting below given message while running WEBrick.

> auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds is set but will be ignored because
>   your adapter does not support this feature. Please unset the
>   configuration to avoid this warning.

I am using:

> gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
>   gem 'mysql'
>
> WEBrick 1.3.1
>   ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

Can somebody help me knowing - why i am getting this and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted, you could comment out the config, and the error would go away, but it is trying to tell you that you have a slow query, and you'd probably want to know what's going on there.

It should work if you try the mysql2 gem instead of the mysql gem.

This seems like a duplicate of [undefined method `explain' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057863/undefined-method-explain-for-activerecordconnectionadaptersmysqladapter)

UPDATE:
As @twelve17 noted, the presence of this message in the log doesn't mean that you have a slow query yet, but that your adapter doesn't support the mechanism this uses to tell you when you do have a slow query. I should have said "You don't want to just turn this functionality off, you'd probably want to use the mysql2 gem so you can see when a slow query comes up"

Comment: I think the presence of that log message doesn't necessarily mean you have a slow query, at least on 3.2.13.  [Based on the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4bdaf95b82a1358b11bbfb857a1ac2790136a4ef/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L152), it will print the message if you have the config entry and the adapter doesn't support the feature.

On a side note, it looks like this feature is [going away in Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3688e02ca52c0b72d3092e8498da51e06b7fc58#activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb).

Answer (score 8):

I came across this error message today in Rails 3 app I was upgrading to 3.2.

> config/environments/development.rb

Commented out this line and it will work:

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

above that line it said:

```
  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
```

and I was using MySQL so I don't really know why it was throwing an error. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is deprecated now so I wouldn't use it: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3688e02ca52c0b72d3092e8498da51e06b7fc58#activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb